# kubectl with Docker Desktop - how to connect

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, docker-desktop

I was using kubectl with Docker Desktop - everything was fine

I think logged into Openshift via the Command line and kubectl seemed to point to OC cluster

I then logged out of Openshift and now kubectl doesn't seem to point at anything? How do I get to point it at docker desktop again?

Answer (score 2):

sorted - kubectl config use-context docker-desktop